# Unrecognized process state output in ps command

Tags: process, ps

Running `ps aux` in an `Ubuntu 18.04` I see some processes having state `I`, as in...

```
root         1  0.0  0.0 225520  9144 ?        Ss   10:36   0:02 /sbin/init splash
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:36   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   10:36   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   10:36   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
```

However this state is not mentioned in `ps` manpages:

> PROCESS STATE CODES
>          Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state
>   of a process:
>
> ```
>            D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>            R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>            S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>            T    stopped by job control signal
>            t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
>            W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>            X    dead (should never be seen)
>            Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
>
>    For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
>
>            <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>            N    low-priority (nice to other users)
>            L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
>            s    is a session leader
>            l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
>            +    is in the foreground process group
> ```

What is this `I` state?

Comment: Related - [What does an idle CPU process do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361245/what-does-an-idle-cpu-process-do).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means "Idle"

```
    /* states beyond TASK_REPORT: */
    "I (idle)",             /* 0x80 */
```

Reference: [What does Linux process state "I" mean in the top output?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Linux-process-state-I-mean-in-the-top-output#)

> Digging more in kernel sources I found that the record for I is `TASK_REPORT_IDLE`, which is returned from kernel guts (function `__get_task_state`) when process has status TASK_IDLE, which in fact is a combination of
>
> ```
> #define TASK_IDLE   (TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE | TASK_NOLOAD)
> ```

Also, see this commit to the kernel titled: [sched/wait: Introduce TASK_NOLOAD and TASK_IDLE](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=80ed87c8a9ca0cad7ca66cf3bbdfb17559a66dcf).

> Currently people use `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` to idle `kthreads` and wait for
>   'work' because `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` contributes to the loadavg. Having
>   all idle `kthreads` contribute to the loadavg is somewhat silly.
>
> Now mostly this works OK, because `kthreads` have all their signals
>   masked. However there's a few sites where this is causing problems and
>   `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` should be used, except for that loadavg issue.
>
> This patch adds `TASK_NOLOAD` which, when combined with
>   `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` avoids the loadavg accounting.
>
> As most of imagined usage sites are loops where a thread wants to
>   idle, waiting for work, a helper `TASK_IDLE` is introduced.

**NOTE:** This appears to have been added to the [Linux kernel in 4.14-rc3](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/10/1/182):

> sched/debug: Add explicit TASK_IDLE printing

#### /proc

Given this is coming from the Linux kernel, downstream tools such as `ps` and `top` immediately can display this new state, `I`, without having to be explicitly told, since they derive their information from `/proc`.

You can see a `/proc`'s state via the `/proc/<PID>/stat`:

```
$ cat /proc/10/stat
10 (lru-add-drain) S 2 0 0 0 -1 69247072 ....
                   ^--- state = S = Sleep
```

#### References

- [man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)